# Using Netbean how do i run the jframe with image

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author BOUORON
 */
public class register extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form login
     */
    public register() {
        initComponents();
    }

    ImageIcon user = new ImageIcon("user.png");
    ImageIcon lock = new ImageIcon("lock.png");
```

Basically my inside my jframe when there is an image it wont run the jframe out, it said build success but it wont show up, when there is no image, the jframe will run, how do I solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify the problem. If I understand correctly, your JFrame will be displayed as long as you don't load an image. But as soon as you load this, the JFrame is no longer displayed. Or is it just the image that is not displayed? It would certainly help if you added your code snippet that draws the image.

Answer (score 2):

can you use `set visible` true...

```
 frmLogin = new JFrame();
        frmLogin.setTitle("Test");
        frmLogin.setBounds(100, 100, 585, 380);
        frmLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmLogin.setVisible(true);
```

like that

Comment: /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

inside my code it only have this, but when I add yours code into it, still doesn't work

Comment: with image only the jframe wont run, not sure why

Comment: i don't understand how to show just an image firstly u need a Jframe in which you show image